# Ctrl+V ( Paste ) triggers jQuery's keyup function TWICE

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

How to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or Paste not trigger the `keyup` function TWICE?

This is a problem for me because I made an AutoComplete functionality, and it displays the same data twice when i paste in a textbox. I hope this makes more sense now.

EDIT:

Okay guys, I have found out how to detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> by `$('#this-id').bind('paste', function() {});`

But now another follow up question is how to combine it with `keyup` so that when `paste` is pressed, `keyup` wont trigger anymore.

Comment: Why is it a problem for you? You *do* release two keys (V and CTRL) after all...

Comment: Do you have any trials respective to the question asked? actually this question does not make any sense.

Comment: Why don't you use `keydown` to trap the `Ctrl` key and `keyup` to trap the `V` key?

Comment: okay! i have some issues like this before in the inclusion of same script twice, you can check for that.

Comment: Then how about if 'V' is a part of the letters i am typing to search in an autocomplete i made? @RGraham

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay guys, Thank you all for your answers but as I go through some reading, a lot of blogs say this: "**IF you're implementing an autocomplete functionality, DON'T rely on 'keyup' function**"

So I changed my code to `$('#this-id').bind('input', function() {});`

And it worked, I don't have to worry now about pasting or anything else. I hope this helps to others too.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
$(window).on('keyup', function (event) {
    if (!event.ctrlKey) {
        /* here your code for all keys besides CTRL ;-) */
    }
});
```

Comment: I see your point, but I dont want to filter the ctrl key, I want it to be detected only once, because i still want the CTRL + V functionality to work, just not twice. In addition to your answer is there any way to detect if the next key pressed is 'V'?

Comment: I tried this, my autocomplete doesn't work with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use underscore's debounce to set delay for reading the keyup event.

See the working code at:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KEDEp/3/)

JS:

```
var count = 0;
function lookup() {
    $('div#test').html($('input.text').val());
    count++;
    $('div#count').html(count);
}

$(document).keyup( _.debounce(lookup, 250, true) );
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="text">
</div>

Input: <div id="test"></div>
Keyup Count: <div id="count"></div>
```

underscore.js from:

http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js