# onKeyUp causing code to execute twice

Tags: javascript, html

I spent the better half of the last hour trying to figure out what was causing my JavaScript function to execute "twice," as I kept seeing everything duplicated in the developer console.

I finally traced it to this piece of code:

```
<textarea onkeyup="parseInput(this)"></textarea>
```

The purpose of this is to allow a user to paste data into the textbox, then have the function `parseInput()` run as soon as they do. The **issue** with this is that as soon as they hit `CTRL+V`, the function runs. Then, when they RELEASE `CTRL`, the code runs again, (although the data it's sending is an exact duplicate of the data it just sent.)

This is causing my function to trigger twice. I understand that JavaScript must have some way to code the following logic, but I don't know what it is:

If they CTRL key is released I don't run the next bit of code.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `keypress` ..........

Comment: How about `onpaste` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778854/ctrl-v-paste-triggers-jquerys-keyup-function-twice

Comment: Or keep track of the state and add a check to see if text has changed  `if(text===lastText) return`

Comment: I guess I could use `onblur`, to force the user to click out of the box.  This solves the problem, but I'd still like to eliminate that if I could.  `onpaste` and `onkeypress` don't work.

Comment: also - thanks for linking this @BeingHuman!  I searched all over SO for something similar.  A lot of these posts could be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First argument of your function is `event` object. You should check `keyCode` property and chose following logic based on choise.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onkeyup

Comment: The first argument will be the `event` object only if it has been passed, OP has an inline event handler here.